# Ruby push and delete error?

Tags: ruby

I have this code and I don't know why it doesn't give me the correct answer

```
list = [1] 
a = [0,0,2,3,4]

for n in a
  if n!= 0
    list.push(n)
    a.delete(n)
  end
end 

p list => [1,2,4]
p a => [0,0,3]
```

I don't understand why number didn't get added to list. When I tried to only use 'push' and not 'a.delete' I got the correct answers

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
a = [0,0,2,3,4]
```

What is going on?

Comment: You should do a little better job at explaining what you want and why you don't like what you get.

Comment: Remember, you should accept answers that solve your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the output carefully:

```
list = [1] 
a = [0,0,2,3,4]

for n in a
  if n!= 0
    list.push(n)
    a.delete(n)
    p list,a
  end
end
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2]
[0, 0, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[0, 0, 3]
```

So when your loop deleted `2`, which was in the 3rd item before deletion, 3 comes into that position. And as the loop completed the 3rd item processing,it will jump to the take next item from the collection,which is 4. This is how item 3 will be skipped. As after deletion all your item will be *shifted from right to left*. Look below for more clarity to see what is going on inside the loop and state of collection `a` after each delete.

```
list = [1] 
a = [0,0,2,3,4]

for n in a
  if n!= 0
    p n
    i = a.find_index(n)
    list.push(n)
    a.delete(n)
    p a[i]
    p "-" *8
  end
end
```

*output:*

```
2
3
"--------"
4
nil
"--------"
```

Comment: Your answer could benefit greatly from a couple of pseudo-graphic illustrations of the process.

Comment: @RubyLovely: I posted the comment before you added that last paragraph.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have given the intermediate outputs also.

Comment: Wasn't me, if you're interested. :) I get some random downvotes too.

Comment: @RubyLovely: I don't upvote just to balance somebody's downvote (and you shouldn't too). But you have a good answer, so here's a +1 from me :)

Answer (score 4):

Rule number one of iterating collections: **don't change the collection you're currently iterating!**.

A quick fix would be to iterate a **copy** of the collection.

```
list = [1] 
a = [0,0,2,3,4]

for n in a.dup # here, a copy
  if n!= 0
    list.push(n)
    a.delete(n)
  end
end 

list # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a # => [0, 0]
```

Comment: Thanks but do you have any idea why the 3 was just skipped?

Comment: @RubyLovely has posted the explanation in his answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is this `list # => [1, 2, 3, 4]` automatically in your editor or you do edit this way? As I am running ST2 where output comes in different window, and I need to copy there from and paste it to here,which causes slower posting :)

Comment: @RubyLovely: Yes, textmate inserts output for me. That's why I post so fast :)

Comment: @RubyLovely, to use the `# =>` feature in ST2, check out this post: [Execute and Update Markers](http://superuser.com/questions/472413/is-there-a-way-to-execute-and-update-markers-in-sublime-text-2/472464#comment601183_472464) and the resulting ST2 package [ST2-Ruby-Markers](https://github.com/mmims/sublime-text-2-ruby-markers)

Comment: how to install it on ubuntu and make the settings,like I can also post quickly.

Comment: can you join the chat for a while?

Comment: @AGS: that's my question! :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, between your question and the resulting ST2 package, and using SublimeREPL w/ PRY, Ruby output has never been faster or easier.

Comment: @AGS: ehm, so what's faster and easier, exactly? I'm afraid I fail to parse your comment.

Comment: @AGS can you join here please? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30866/discussion-between-rubylovely-and-sergio-tulentsev